# Dressler's Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

At the moment I am into a problem which depends intensively on the distribution of prime numbers. I noticed that I wish to know the following statement:

**Dessler's Conjecture**: Between any two positive integers having the same prime factors there is a prime.

The first person to formulate it was Robert Dressler. Cochrane and Dressler wrote a paper with some related results in 1999.

Now I want to know if there was made some effort since then. Maybe the conjecture is even solved.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Here's a discussion from 2017: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287011/a-conjecture-regarding-prime-numbers Pomerance mentions the Dressler conjecture in a talk from 2016: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/abctalk.pdf

Comment: Waldschmidt 2018 has it as open, https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/abcEnVI.pdf Do you have access to a library with MathSciNet?

Comment: Thank you! @Gerry Myerson: yes, I do.

Comment: OK, then, the review of the Cochrane-Dressler paper should mention more recent papers that have cited it, if any.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: If you find anything, you could write up a summary, and post it as an answer.